# How to create background services to run even when the app is killed, in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, multitasking

I need to create a android equivalent functionality in iOS, which records GPS and other sensor readings even when the app is killed, in iOS that would be, when the app is swiped from the app switcher.

In android, the `Service` class is able to do this. The notification stays there in the notification panel and you cannot swipe it, unless the app allows you to do so..

Many apps add widgets to the notification panel using this functionality like, clean master. Clean master widget floats in the notification panel and does most of the functionality which the app does it self.

Comment: Just in case some all rounder (iOS Android ) guy/god found this and have some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

IOS does not has any background service concept. Yes, you can use GPS location when user app in background but it will not work when your app is totally close.